# How to model a vector of non-owning raw pointers extracted from unique_ptrs?

Tags: c++

**Note**: Apologies if the title is unclear, I don't quite know how to express the issue in proper terms (improvement suggestions are very welcome).

Code, [onlinegdb example of the working version](https://onlinegdb.com/rkH7qOZFv) and [example of the non-working one](https://onlinegdb.com/HkWdcdWYP) first to simplify the explanation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    int v = 0;
};

void some_library_function(const std::vector<A*>& objects)
{
    // do something to each object without taking ownership
    for(auto p : objects)
    {
        p->v = 42;
    }
}

class B
{
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> m_objects; // this is a private field in my actual code

    B():m_objects{std::make_shared<A>()}{};

    void use_library()
    {
        std::vector<A*> observer_vector(m_objects.size());
        for(int i=0; i<m_objects.size(); i++)
        {
            observer_vector[i] = m_objects[i].get(); // fails here if I use unique_ptr
        }
        some_library_function(observer_vector);
    }
};


int main()
{
    B b;
    b.use_library();
    std::cout << b.m_objects[0]->v;
    return 0;
}
```

I have a library function that operates on a series of objects of class `A` passed in via `std::vector<A*>`. These objects are stored in a field of class `B` that owns the objects. I would like to model the "owns" part via a vector of `std::vector<unique_ptr<A>>`, but this makes it impossible to pass the objects down to the library function.
using `shared_ptr`s works, but I'm worried this is not as expressive as the unique_ptrs with regards to object ownership.

Is there a way to use `unique_ptr`s in the vector and still be able to use the library function?

Comment: `unique_ptr` is failing because `B():m_objects{std::make_unique<A>()}{}` won't work.  A unique_ptr is not copy-able, only move-able.  You'll need `B(){m_objects.emplace_back(std::make_unique<A>());}` instead.

Comment: @Eljay That indeed is the reason of the error! I thought it was possible to have moveable-but-not-copyable objects in an initializer list, but I see now that this is not the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already doing the right thing. A raw pointer is a perfectly reasonable way to model something with unknown or lacking ownership. You're not storing the vector anywhere, so there is no confusion and no risk.

The only problem here really is that you've had to regenerate the entire vector, which seems like a bit of a waste. Ultimately, if you're set on a `vector<unique_ptr<A>>` at the source, and you're stuck with `vector<A*>` at the destination, then there's nothing you can do about that. If the vector is small it doesn't really matter though.

---

> ```
> observer_vector[i] = m_objects[i].get(); // fails if with unique_ptr because of operator= being deleted
> ```

No, that should be valid. You're just assigning a raw pointer.

Comment: I added links to onlinegdb for the version with shared_ptr and with unique_ptr. Could you have a look at the second one and the error message? I also thought the assignment should be valid, but the code doesn't compile and I'm not sure anymore of the reason why

Comment: @GPhilo Read the errors more closely; they're pointing to line 33, not the assignment. `B():m_objects{std::make_unique<A>()}{};` can't work - not sure what it's supposed to do anyway?

Comment: Yes, I got confused when reading the error message. It's supposed to fill `m_objects` with one item, but I didn't know that objects in an initializer list are copied and not moved into the vector, as pointed out by Eljay in his comment to the question.